# If a function's 1st derivative is bounded, does this imply that the function must also be bounded?

Tags: real-analysis

Same as below, if $f'$ is bounded at the open interval, does this imply that $f$ is also bounded at the open interval?

Comment: Do you mean to require that the interval is finite?

Comment: Well, i got an exercise that says that $f'$ is bounded at the $(x1,x2)$ where $x1 < x2$, and I need to prove that $f$ is also bounded at the same interval.

Comment: If that is what you "got", then why didn't you tell us? Also, are $x_1,x_2$ real numbers?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

$f(x)=x$ is unbounded on $\mathbb{R}$, but its derivative is the constant $1$, which is bounded.

If $f$ is differentiable on a bounded open interval $I$ (say $|x|\leq M$ for all $x\in I$) and $f^{\prime}$ is continuous on $I$ with $|f^{\prime}(x)|\leq C$ on $I$, then choosing some $a\in I$ we have
$$ f(x)=f(a)+\int_a^xf^{\prime}(t)\;dt $$
for all $x\in I$ by the Fundamental Theorem of Calculus, hence 
$$ |f(x)|\leq|f(a)|+|C||x-a|\leq |f(a)|+2CM $$
so $f$ is in fact bounded.

Answer (score 2):

Not necessarily.

For example consider the function $f(x)=x$, $ \ D_f=\mathbb{R}$, which is (obviously) unbounded, while its derivative is $f'(x)=1$, which is constant, thus bounded (in the same domain).