# Bounded gradient on bounded domain implies that the function is bounded

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, multivariable-calculus, derivatives

Let $\mathit U \subset \mathbb R^n$ be a bounded Domain,$\,$ $ \mathit f : $ $\mathit U \to \mathbb R $ differentiable, with $\nabla f$ bounded. Does this imply that $\, \mathit f \,$ is bounded on $\mathit U$ ?
In the case of n = 1, by FTC it should be true, same goes if the Domain is convex. In the general case, I have trouble proving/giving a counterexample, maybe someone can help?

Comment: I think you can find a counterexample on $U:=$ the unit disc minus some spiral asymptotic to the unit circle.

Comment: For the $n=1$ case you need U to be closed AND bounded, right? I'm thinking the same thing applies in the general case. $df=\nabla f \cdot \vec{ds}$ essentially reduces the multi-dimensional case to the 1D case.

Comment: @TurlocTheRed For n = 1 I don't think closedness is required. Since $\mathit U$ is a   Domain ( open and connected), and the connected subsets of the real line are Intervalls it follows, that $\mathit U$ is an open, bounded Intervall. Now the argument is similar as in this answer[link] (https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1964348/if-a-functions-1st-derivative-is-bounded-does-this-imply-that-the-function-mus)

Comment: @AnneBauval could you maybe expand a little bit, please?

Comment: @Mememaster696 following Anne Bauval's comment, define $g(p)=\theta(p)$ (in polar coordinates)  at some point on the unit disc minus a spiral that approaches the origin and is asymptotic to the unit circle.  Then show $g$ has a unique continuous extension that coincides with the usual angular coordinate $\theta$ up to an integer multiple of $2\pi$.  $g$ will have unbounded gradient, but $rg$ will have bounded gradient yet be unbounded as you approach the unit circle.

Comment: @MW Aha I see. Thank you for your help.